# Styling footer with variable number of paragraphs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I am writing an application which allows to define styles that will be applied to rich text elements. A style specifies the attributes for individual paragraphs, and indicates how many of them are in the header, body and footer. The rich text elements to which the style will be applied may contain any number of paragraphs. A simplified example is shown in the code snippet below.

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.container > p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Body paragraphs */
.container > :nth-child(2n+2) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: silver;
}

.container > :nth-child(2n+3) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: gray;
}

/* Footer paragraphs */
.container > :nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

.container > :nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

.container > :nth-last-child(-n+1) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

/* Header paragraphs */
.container > :nth-child(2) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: fuchsia;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.container > :nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: red;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
    <p>Paragraph 3
    <p>Paragraph 4
    <p>Paragraph 5
    <p>Paragraph 6
    <p>Paragraph 7
    <p>Paragraph 8
    <p>Paragraph 9
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
    <p>Paragraph 3
    <p>Paragraph 4
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
    <p>Paragraph 3
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
</div>
```

The header paragraphs are styled in priority, then the footer paragraphs, and the body styling is applied repeatedly as often as necessary to the remaining paragraphs. I got most of the behavior right but the footer is not always styled as I would like. As the number of paragraphs decreases, I would like to keep the styling of the top of the footer and lose the bottom, but I get the opposite result.

In the image below, the 2 header paragraphs have a gray background and the 3 footer paragraphs have a yellow background. In the case where the rich text has 5 or more paragraphs, all of the styling is applied. But when the rich text has 4 paragraphs, only 2 paragraphs of the footer can be displayed, and I would like to keep the styling of the 2 top paragraphs: the green and blue ones in the present case. Using `:nth-last-child`, I don't see how to give a higher priority to the top styling of the footer. Can it be done with CSS selectors?

[image]

Comment: I cut your markup down to size to make it a little bit easier to skim, but left your snippet collapsed. Feel free to uncollapse it after the fact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this by ensuring that each footer rule only applies when the element is the 3rd child counting from the top onwards using `:nth-child(n+3)` to `:nth-child(n+5)`. By using `:nth-last-child(-n+3)` to `:nth-last-child(-n+1)` to style your footer paragraphs you're already partway there; you can simply add the respective `:nth-child()` to each selector.

```css
/* Footer paragraphs */
.container > :nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

.container > :nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

.container > :nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(-n+1) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}
```

```css
.container {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin-right: 20px;
}

.container > p {
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 8px;
    padding-right: 8px;
}

/* Body paragraphs */
.container > :nth-child(2n+2) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: silver;
}

.container > :nth-child(2n+3) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: gray;
}

/* Footer paragraphs */
.container > :nth-child(n+3):nth-last-child(-n+3) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: green;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

.container > :nth-child(n+4):nth-last-child(-n+2) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: blue;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

.container > :nth-child(n+5):nth-last-child(-n+1) {
    font-weight: bold;
    color: black;
    background-color: #ffffa0;
}

/* Header paragraphs */
.container > :nth-child(2) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: fuchsia;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}

.container > :nth-child(1) {
    font-weight: normal;
    color: red;
    background-color: #f0f0f0;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
    <p>Paragraph 3
    <p>Paragraph 4
    <p>Paragraph 5
    <p>Paragraph 6
    <p>Paragraph 7
    <p>Paragraph 8
    <p>Paragraph 9
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
    <p>Paragraph 3
    <p>Paragraph 4
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
    <p>Paragraph 3
</div>
<div class="container">
    <p>Paragraph 1
    <p>Paragraph 2
</div>
```

There are lots of duplicated styles in your CSS, but I'm leaving them untouched to make it easier for you to see the changes that actually matter.